# Collision with "Uninitialized Stack Pointer"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I was recently informed that MSVC's debug-mode marker for uninitialized stack memory is 0xCCCCCCCC. I'm worried now; although unlikely, what happens if malloc()/new/any pointer ends up coincidentally as this pointer? Would it throw an error? Could this cause problems in important systems??

Comment: _"what happens if malloc()/new/any pointer ends up coincidentally as this pointer?"_ That won't happen of course, MS developers may not seem to be the smartest, but they aren't that stoopid.

Comment: There is nothing magical or special about 0xCCCCCCCC.  If malloc()/new ends up allocated from the heap at that location, then it'll be a valid location.

Comment: That's a trap value... by itself it is in illegal address range. It allows to identify uninitialized storage. Coincedally HeapAlloc and alike initialize memory with 0xbaadf00d

Comment: Won't happen, that address can only be mapped to ring0 pages (OS kernel and drivers).  And thus reliably generates an AVE.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space

Comment: *"what happens if malloc()/new/any pointer ends up coincidentally as this pointer?"* -- Good thought. Can you think of something better than `0xCCCCCCCC` to use as the marker? Any thoughts as to why MSVC does not use your "something better" idea?

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` is required by the standard to be suitably aligned to store any kind of variable and `new` to return a pointer suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer of any complete object type.

`0xCCCCCCCC` has `2^2` in it's factorization which means that the highest alignment is  4-byte alignment (it is not divisible by 8). So on x86 in MSVC (where `long long` is 8 bytes) `malloc` and `new` will never return `0xCCCCCCCC`.

---

This is a thing I thought of, I am sure there's more to the story.

Comment: I should add out that the filling of memory with 0xcccccccc is only an aid to debugging and is not really something you should rely on, or check for.

Comment: Yeah but MSVC can definitely also run on 32 bit systems; would it be possible then?

Comment: x86 is a 32 bit platform. On msvc x86 `long long` is 8 bytes